# Questions about latex formula numbering(counter)

Tags: equations, subequations

I want get the formula number like the first picture
[image]

but when I use the code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha_{i}^{2}&=\beta^{2}=1\\
\alpha_{i} \alpha_{j}&=-\alpha_{j} \alpha_{i}\\
\alpha_{i} \beta&=-\beta \alpha_{i}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

I can only get the formula number like the second picture:
[image]

What should I do to get the formula number I want?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of nesting an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment, you should nest an `align` environment inside a `subequations` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' and 'subequations' environments
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{1}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\alpha_{i}^{2}&=\beta^{2}=1\\
\alpha_{i} \alpha_{j}&=-\alpha_{j} \alpha_{i}\\
\alpha_{i} \beta&=-\beta \alpha_{i}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, the problem has been solved perfectly.

Comment: @user248841 - Glad you found my answer useful. If you feel like, do please click the check-mark symbol next to the vote count "button" to accept this answer. ;-)